# Problem in compiling a latex file in Dropbox

Tags: compiling, dropbox

[image]

When I am compiling a .tex file in my laptop then it is fine but after attaching this file in Dropbox and compiling in Dropbox then it is not compiling and above message is shown. Please help.

Comment: Please do not compile files on Dropbox. Rather, use soft links to link them to a local directory in which you compile. Once you share the file(s) with others, they will appreciate very much not getting the auxiliary files from your compilation on their machines.

Comment: So what you suggest! Copy the latex file from Dropbox to my machine, then do the necessary edit and re-upload the edited file to dropbox and share ?

Comment: I have very little knowledge about this. Please bother my ignorance.

Comment: I am using soft links. On a Linux machine or a Mac, creating them is as simple as typing ‘ln -s <path to Dropbox file>’ in a local directory. Then there is absolutely no manual copying required, and the Dropbox folder is kept clean and tidy, only the source files are there.

Comment: I am using original windows 10. Can you please direct me where and what to do. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I abandoned Windows for good a very long time ago. AFAIK it does have some sort of soft links, but I do not know anything about how they work.

Comment: Okay thanks for ur time